# Unable to use html helper of external api on razor page to display relative time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, hangfire

I am having a datetime value like below :

```
2018-04-16 20:59:41.870
```

For above datetime i want to display relative time like below :

> a minute ago
>
> 5 hours ago

I am trying to use api shown [HERE](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/master/src/Hangfire.Core/Dashboard/Pages/ProcessingJobsPage.cshtml) which contains api to display relative time like below but i am unable to use its api :

[image]

Though i have included its api but getting error on RelativeTime :

```
@using Hangfire.Dashboard
@using Hangfire.Dashboard.Pages
@using Hangfire.Dashboard.Resources
```

This is how api is used is shown on their site : https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/master/src/Hangfire.Core/Dashboard/Pages/ProcessingJobsPage.cshtml

[image]

**Note :** `myDate` is **angular js scope variable**.

I will appreciate any help :)

**Update :** 
[image]

Comment: It expects DateTime object, but you are passing some string there.

Comment: You seem not to have understood that Razor code is executed on the server, before the page is sent to the user. Angular code is JavaScript, and executed in the browser, after the page is loaded. Therefore when `@Html.RelativeTime` executes, at that moment `{{myDate}}` has not been evaluated into a date (because the Angular code cannot run yet), so as far as the Razor code is concerned, you're just asking it to parse a random string into a date, which is not possible. You need to re-think your approach and understand the lifecycle of your page.

Comment: @Evk I have updated my question to include datetime but still same error prevails

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for the explanation.I got your point.I have updated which now includes datetime but still same error prevails

Comment: why have you got the @ in front of it? You're already in a Razor code block.

Comment: But here they are using : https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/master/src/Hangfire.Core/Dashboard/Pages/ProcessingJobsPage.cshtml

Comment: Not the same as being in a whole `@{ ... }` code block. In that page the preceeding `@` is specifically attached on the `if`, not declaring a whole block.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169152/discussion-between-user-and-adyson).

Comment: @ADyson But still the error is same even if i remove @

Comment: Try using this method _outside_ the code block (but with the @) so it can be rendered into the HTML. Also ensure you've included any libraries which are needed for this to be used. Not sure it's part of the standard MVC helpers

Comment: @ADyson Still same problem.No it is not part of standard mvc helpers but it as part of Hangfire api as shown here :http://api.hangfire.io/html/M_Hangfire_Dashboard_HtmlHelper_RelativeTime.htm